# Getting errors with Android.bp when trying to build a static java library

Tags: java, android, jar, android-source, android.mk

I am looking for a way to build a static jar library from my below definition in Android.bp. I am using Android-12 OS.

```
// Define the module type
java_library_static {
    name: "com.example.foo.player",
    srcs: [
        "src/com/example/foo/player/**/*.java",
    ],
}
```

With this definition, when I try to build the jar file using AOSP project source code, I am getting the below errors.

```
error: system/vold/Android.bp:106:1: dependency "libsysprop-vendor" of "libvold" missing variant:
os:android,image:,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:static
available variants:
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk: (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:static
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:
os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:latest (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon (alias to os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk: (alias to os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:static
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared (alias to os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:
os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:latest (alias to os:android,image:product.31,arch:arm_armv7-a-neon,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
15:50:30 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

Can someone share any solutions for these, if faced them earlier? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did the repo sync complete properly? Here it looks vold is screaming missing system/libsysprop.

Comment: Hi @RajatGupta, yes repo sync completed successfully. And I was also able to create a PKG with AOSP full source code.